# Advanced search form doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, each

I'm following Advanced search form episode from Railscasts

this is the search model.

```
  search.rb
  class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :keywords

   def segnalazione_animalis
    @segnalazione_animalis ||= find_segnalazione_animalis
   end

  private
  def find_segnalazione_animalis
  segnalazione_animalis = SegnalazioneAnimali.order(:Titolo)
  segnalazione_animalis = segnalazione_animalis.where("Titolo like ?", "%#{keywords}%")            
                                                                   if keywords.present?
  segnalazione_animalis
  end
  end
```

I have a searches_controller.rb

```
    class SearchesController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @search = Search.new
    end
    def create
       @search = Search.create!(params[:search])
       redirect_to @search
    end
    def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end
    end
```

The new.html.erb file is

```
       <%= form_for @search do |f| %>
       <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :keywords %><br />
       <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
       </div>

        <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
       <% end %>
```

And the show file:

```
       <h1>Search Results</h1>
       <%= render @search.segnalazione_animalis %>
```

I take the partial rendered from the index file of my segnalazione_animalis folder:

```
       _segnalazione_animali.html.erb
            <table class="table1">
            <tr>
            <th>Titolo:</th><br>
            <th>Classe:</th>
            <th>Creato il:</th>
            <th>Ultima Modifica il:</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>

            <% @segnalazione_animalis.each do |segnalazione_animali| %>

            <tr>
            <td><%= segnalazione_animali.Titolo  %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%= segnalazione_animali.classe %>
            <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.created_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")</td>
            <td><%= l(segnalazione_animali.updated_at, format:"%e %B %Y %k:%M:%S")%>                 
            </td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Mostra', [segnalazione_animali.user, segnalazione_animali] 
                               %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
            </table>
```

When I search something I have the following error:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I think I must add something in the controller but I don't know what!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line in `_segnalazione_animali.html.erb` to

```
<% @search.segnalazione_animalis.each do |segnalazione_animali| %>
```

Comment: I've another problem now...when it find more than one result it shows more tables! es. it find 2 results it shows two tables with these two results!

Comment: @tettoroberto Read a bit on how to render partials, it's good reading anyway. The answer is there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: thanks! I'll read it as soon as possible! I'm in the "ruby on rails world" by few time and i'd like to learn more!